# Programmatically get gem versions from Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Over in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419221/query-dependency-list-from-within-a-rails-app), an answer was given to analyze the Bundler dependency list. That works great, but it doesn't give you the list of packages and versions actually being used, because of ">=" dependencies. Is there a way to get the list of packages and versions actually being used rather than just what the dependencies are?

Comment: I'd like the returned info to be much like the information requested in that other question, ie:

[["actionmailer" "3.1.3"]
 ["coffeescript" "2.0.2"]]

Comment: Do you mean get a list of gems being used for a project that has been already bundle installed?  Or do you mean what the other question has asked where there is no Gemfile access?

Comment: Assume no access to the Gemfile. The answer to the other question returns what is in the Gemfile (with the "~>" and ">=" on the versions); what I need is the exact installed version information.

Comment: what is the use case for this?  To know the exact versions of something you would have to query the gemservers/sources and determine what is the newest gem that can satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the way to do this is similar to what was posted in the other question:

```
 Rails.logger.debug "Type is " + Bundler.environment.specs.class.to_s
 Rails.logger.debug "Value is " + Bundler.environment.specs.to_hash.to_s
```

Produces:

```
    Type is Bundler::SpecSet
    Value is {"activemodel"=>[#<Gem::Specification name=activemodel version=3.1.3>],
              "actionpack"=>[#<Gem::Specification name=actionpack version=3.1.3>],
              "actionmailer"=>[#<Gem::Specification name=actionmailer version=3.1.3>]}
```

This code will print out all of the gems and versions being used in your current environment. One thing to note about the answer in that other question is that it will return all of the dependencies, even those that aren't in your current rails environment (for example, the ones that are in your "test" gem grouping).

Answer (score 2):

This code was extracted from the Bundler codebase and will do the exact same thing as `bundle list` from within a Rails console.

```
Bundler.load.specs.sort_by(&:name).each{|s| puts "  * #{s.name} (#{s.version}#{s.git_version})"}; nil
```

If you just want an array of the dependencies, this will also suffice.

```
Bundler.load.specs.map{|s| "#{s.name} (#{s.version}#{s.git_version})"}
```

Comment: User for some reason has no access to Gemfile/Gemfile.lock.  Otherwise they can simply type bundle list.